# MySQL MyISAM corrupt table, how to restore?

Tags: mysql, corruption, myisam

I have a MySQL MyISAM table that's corrupt.  It first showed up in my mysql log as:

```
[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mydb/mytable' is marked as crashed 
and last (automatic?) repair failed
```

I then ran `CHECK TABLE` on it, and after churning away for well over an hour, I got this:

```
+--------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                 |
+--------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| mydb.mytable | check | warning  | Table is marked as crashed and last repair failed        |
| mydb.mytable | check | warning  | 5 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly |
| mydb.mytable | check | warning  | Size of indexfile is: 215237632      Should be: 4096     |
| mydb.mytable | check | error    | Record-count is not ok; is 4212263   Should be: 0        |
| mydb.mytable | check | warning  | Found 48 deleted space.   Should be 0                    |
| mydb.mytable | check | warning  | Found 1 deleted blocks       Should be: 0                |
| mydb.mytable | check | warning  | Found 8362327 key parts. Should be: 0                    |
| mydb.mytable | check | error    | Corrupt                                                  |
+--------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Does all this indicate that this table is too far gone to be salvageable?  Or should `REPAIR TABLE` still work?  Or are there other options to fix this table without replacing the data?  I'm asking first because this table is pretty huge for my system and I have a feeling that it's going to take a loooong time to know if repair is going to work.

Comment: The output above suggests that MySQL believes the table "Should be" empty. I hope you had backups.

Comment: Actually, `REPAIR TABLE` worked nicely, and quicker than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

I proceeded with `REPAIR TABLE` anyway, figuring that if the table was already too far gone, I had nothing else to lose.  Thankfully, it worked!  The table is back up and functioning normally.